# As of vendors - whose bootloaders are easy to unlock, and whose not?

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock, wiki

The vendors differ in their attitude to unlocking the bootloader. Some require codes for unlocking, some not. Some require proprietary, Windows-only software, other not.

Which of the vendors are friendly to people unlocking the devices and which not? Which of them require obtaining tokens, which require proprietary and not-cross-platform software? Which treat unlocking the bootloader as voiding the warranty?

This is only devices which can run Android.

(I started the community wiki)

Comment: Why the downvotes???

Comment: Probably people who don't understand "community wiki" as in general this is very broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Please fill in the gaps!

## Methods of unlocking

### Unlocked by default or not locked at all

- Fairphone
- ZTE Nubia

### Unlock with fastboot, no token needed

- Google (excluding Verizon variants)
- Huawei (very old models)
- OnePlus
- Xiaomi Android One devices (Mi A1, A2, A2 Lite)

### Unlock with fastboot, token needed

- Huawei (some models, mostly "moderately old" ones)
- Moto (excluding carrier or Amazon Prime variants)

### Unlock without fastboot, no token needed

- Samsung (some models, often non-Snapdragon and non-carrier variants; requires enabling OEM Unlocking in Settings, or using official CROM Service app)

### Unlock with proprietary software only, token needed

- Xiaomi non-Android One devices (Windows-only software, unofficial flashers for other OSes - but still closed-source)

*Note:  [There are some important changes regarding unlocking bootloader application status and reason on MIUI based devices](http://en.miui.com/thread-410945-1-1.html):*

> The process is  now simplified and the permission is granted
>   automatically. You **don't have to fill in the application form or
>   wait for the SMS anymore**. Login and head towards
>   http://en.miui.com/unlock to download Mi Unlock Tool

*Important: Bind your Mi Account in Developer options → Mi Unlock and follow the waiting period shown in Mi Unlock Tool*

### Not unlock-able (unless by exposing a vulnerability)

- BlackBerry
- HMD Nokia (Can be unlocked with a token, but only a few XDA members know how to obtain it, and they don't publish the method)
- Huawei (application for Honor unlock code still in limited availability to XDA users [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-view-10/development/honor-bootloader-unlocking-limited-t3837880))

## Effects on warranty

### Does not void warranty

- OnePlus

### Unlocking the bootloader voids the warranty

Comment: Almost all retail Moto devices can be unlocked with a token, at least since the original Moto G... The list is quite long, but I don't believe any Amazon Prime or carrier branded Moto device can be bootloader unlocked.

Comment: No, not all Android One devices can be unlocked. Nokia devices are a good example, they cannot be unlocked officially (there are some hacks to do it on some models/versions, but nothing officially supported).

Comment: DC-Unlocker still offers service to read unlock codes of any Huawei device, though for a fee. Better than not being to fiddle with it entirely.

Comment: Modified a bit. Not sure where Samsung devices fit in this list - they don't have `fastboot` but some of them are really easy to unlock (just flip a switch and flash away in Odin).

Comment: @AndyYan is it true for all Samsung devices? If not, please mention it in the wiki post

Comment: I felt the situation of Samsung device was hard to explain within one or two lines, but since @iBug already added it in, I'll try to make it clear within my knowledge.

Comment: HMD Nokia's unlock tokens are obtained by purchasing an unlock token from TechMesto. It isn't an "xda secret". https://www.techmesto.com/buy-nokia-bootloader-unlock-key/

Comment: "without fastboot" should be reworded, as xiaomi's proprietary software is also "without fastboot". Maybe the intent is "without the need of an external program, from within the original ROM"?

Comment: Xiaomi's software still requires you to boot into fastboot mode, and I believe the proprietary tool still issues fastboot commands, just not directly visible (it shouldn't be since it's tied to account info).

Comment: It actually uses `fastboot` behind the scenes: https://github.com/mc-17/xiaomi-bootloader